# Identify spikes/peaks in density plot by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

[image]

I created a density plot with `ggplot2` package for `R`. I would like to identify the spikes/peaks in the plot which occur between 0.01 and 0.02. There are too many legends to pick it out so I deleted all legends. I tried to filter my data out to find most number of rows that a group has between 0.01 and 0.02. Then I filtered out the selected group to see whether the spike/peak is gone but no, it is there plotted still. Can you suggest a way to identify these spikes/peaks in these plots?

Here is some code :

```
ggplot(NumofHitsnormalized, aes(NumofHits_norm, fill = name)) + geom_density(alpha=0.2) + theme(legend.position="none") + xlim(0.0 , 0.15) 

## To filter out the data that is in the range of first spike
test <- NumofHitsnormalized[which(NumofHitsnormalized$NumofHits_norm > 0.01 & NumofHitsnormalized$NumofHits_norm <0.02),] 

## To figure it out which group (name column) has the most number of rows ##thus I thought maybe I could get the data that lead to spike
testMatrix <- matrix(ncol=2, nrow= length(unique(test$name))) 
for (i in 1:length(unique(test$name))){ 
testMatrix[i,1] <- unique(test$name)[i] 
testMatrix[i,2] <- nrow(unique(test$name)[i])}
```

[image: extremeValues]

Konrad,

This is the new plot made after I filtered my data out with extremevalues package. There are new peaks and they are located at different intervals and it also says 96% of the initial groups have data in the new plot (though number of rows in filtered data reduced to 0.023% percent of the initial dataset) so I cant identify which peaks belong to which groups.

Comment: I question the term "outlier". I seem to vaguely remember a famous statistician saying something along the lines of "whenever I see an extreme unexpected result I never sure whether I should throw it out or patent it.".

Comment: Surely it is possible to show some code???

Comment: Have a look at the package [`extremevalues`](https://github.com/markvanderloo/extremevalues) ([PDF](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extremevalues/extremevalues.pdf)) it should deliver what you need.

Comment: add to your post, not in the comment section

Comment: you could also take a look at the turnpoints() from the pastecs package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem to this.

How i did was to create a rolling mean and sd of the y values with a 3 window.

Calculate the average sd of your baseline data ( the data you know won't have peaks)

Set a threshold value

If above threshold, 1, else 0.

```
d5$roll_mean = runMean(d5$`Current (pA)`,n=3)
d5$roll_sd = runSD(x = d5$`Current (pA)`,n = 3)
d5$delta = ifelse(d5$roll_sd>1,1,0)
currents = subset(d5,d5$delta==1,na.rm=TRUE) # Finds all peaks
```

my threshold was a sd > 1. depending on your data you may want to use mean or sd. for slow rising peaks mean would be a better idea than sd.

Comment: is this caTools package runmean function ?

Comment: yes, there is also rollmean in the zoo package or you can code it yourself pretty easily. take your pick!

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the code, I drafted this simple function to add `TRUE/FALSE` flags to variables indicating outliers:

```
GenerateOutlierFlag <- function(x) {
  # Load required packages
  Vectorize(require)(package = c("extremevalues"), char = TRUE)
  # Run check for ouliers
  out_flg <- ifelse(1:length(x) %in% getOutliers(x, method = "I")$iLeft,
                    TRUE,FALSE)
  out_flg <- ifelse(1:length(x) %in% getOutliers(x, method = "I")$iRight,
                    TRUE,out_flg)
  return(out_flg)
}
```

If you care to read about the **[`extremevalues`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extremevalues/extremevalues.pdf)** package you will see that it provides some flexibility in terms of identifying outliers but broadly speaking it's a good tool for finding various *peaks* or *spikes* in the data.

---

## Side point

*You could actually optimise it significantly by creating one object corresponding to `getOutliers(x, method = "I")` instead of calling the method twice.*

### More sensible syntax

```
GenerateOutlierFlag <- function(x) {
  # Load required packages
  require("extremevalues")
  # Outliers object
  outObj <- getOutliers(x, method = "I")
  # Run check for ouliers
  out_flg <- ifelse(1:length(x) %in% outObj$iLeft,
                    TRUE,FALSE)
  out_flg <- ifelse(1:length(x) %in% outObj$iRight,
                    TRUE,out_flg)
  return(out_flg)
}
```

---

## Results

```
x <- c(1:10, 1000000, -99099999)
table(GenerateOutlierFlag(x))
FALSE  TRUE 
   10     2
```